# Formula to find like dates in one column and then calculate difference between the min/max

Tags: excel, excel-formula

Does anyone know the best way to have Excel:

1. Look in one column to find all like dates
2. Calculate total time between min datetime and max datetime
3. Place total in separate column

```
C                                     D 
8/27/2018 14:02       insert total time for each date here, ie:  8/27 00:05:03
8/27/2018 14:01     
8/27/2018 14:01     
8/27/2018 13:57     
8/27/2018 8:56      
8/24/2018 10:01 
8/24/2018 9:36      
8/23/2018 6:01  
8/21/2018 12:32 
8/21/2018 11:23     
8/20/2018 14:03 
8/20/2018 10:54     
8/17/2018 14:47
```

I used `=TEXT(C7-C8, "h:mm:ss")`, but this is not working for me at all. Would I add a vlookup to it?

Comment: You could split your column so `C` = `Date` and `D` = `time` and then you can simply use `MAXIFS` - `MINIFS`

Answer (score 0):

This solution will require that you create a UDF (User-Defined Function) in VBA.

Essentially, you will loop to find all matching dates in your column. On all the dates that match, you will modify the `minDt` and `maxDt` variables as necessary - which if the new time is lower or higher than what you currently have stored.

This is probably not the best solution, as creating a UDF that contains a loop is going to be somewhat of a bottleneck, but this is what I am able to come up with at the moment.

```vb
Option Explicit

Function getTimeDiff(col As String, inputDt As Date)

    Dim colRng As Range, compDt As Date
    Set colRng = Columns(col)

    compDt = Int(inputDt)   '<-- Converts date/time to date only

    Dim cel As Range, maxDt As Date, minDt As Date, tmpDt As Date
    maxDt = inputDt
    minDt = inputDt
    For Each cel In colRng.Cells
        If cel = "" Then Exit For
        tmpDt = CDate(cel)
        If Int(tmpDt) = compDt Then
            If tmpDt > maxDt Then 
                maxDt = tmpDt
            ElseIf tmpDt < minDt Then 
                minDt = tmpDt
            End If
        End If
    Next cel

    getTimeDiff = Format(maxDt - minDt, "h:mm")

End Function
```

> ### Read here on creating UDFs
>
> *If you are familiar with UDFs, you may skip this section*
>
> - Press  <kbd>Alt</kbd>  +  <kbd>F11</kbd>  to open up VBA.
> - In the VBE, click **Insert** > **Module**
> - Paste the above code into the module
> - Save as a **Macro-Enabled Workbook**

Once you have saved the UDF, you may now use your newly create formula.

It appears that your dates are in column C. So, if your first date was in `C2`, your formula for `D2` would be:

```
=getTimeDiff("C", C2)
```

[image]